# Помощь в оптимизации кода

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Используя массивы и квадратный корень доработать программу с целью ускорения вычислений.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n, i, j;
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 2; (i % j) != 0; j++)
        {
            ;//Не делаем в теле ничего.
        }
        if (j == i) cout << i << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что ваш код то делает? Какое изначальное условие задачи?

Comment: Программа вывода простых чисел. Нужно было разобраться как работает программа и оптимизировать ее, как написано выше, с последним возникли трудности.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229599/Как-сделать-код-максимально-быстрым/1229614#1229614) много вариантов поиска простых чисел. А вообще можно идти от `2` до `sqrt(n)` а не до `n`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!